# How do I remap the left and right hands to mouse buttons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to change right/left hand in the controls menu, so I map left hand with M1 and it works, but then the cursor freezes and it's still saying "Press a button to map this action." And if I click anything else (say e or enter), it maps those button to the action and I basically can't get out of the menu with mapping M1 to left hand, if that makes sense.
So how can I do it?

Comment: I've tried that, At first it says
LeftHand M2
RightHand M1 Go to right hand and switch it to M2 and they switch around
If you go to LeftHand it becomes a bug and it just keeps telling to press a button.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are highlighting the option again and Skyrim is VERY liberal with what it determines as a click. Move the cursor away from the selection after highlighting, then hit e to activate it, then click the desired mouse remap, and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm copying this from a forum where I also replied with this exact same information.

I was having the exact same problem with M1 freezing the cursor and then pressing any other button and it being assigned instead of M1. I figured out a way to get it to work, though.

Press 7 (also called "home") in the number pad side keys on the far right provided you have a standard keyboard. You'll get a message saying "that key is reserved", M1 will still be selected for your left hand and the glitch has been out-matched. :)

Hopefully that'll help anyone having this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

On left hand, click <kbd>M1</kbd> so it binds (it'll then default right hand to <kbd>M2</kbd>), then just roll the mouse wheel a bit.

Works for me, although for some reason I have to do it every time I load the game up.

Comment: Is your INI file read-only?